# Graphical glitch of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, visual-glitch

I have made a sample project after my customers reported a graphical glitch in my software and I managed to reproduce the problem with ease. I create a simple docked DataGridView in a form and I fill it with random data like this:

```
var ds = new DataSet();
var table = ds.Tables.Add();
Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ForEach(i => table.Columns.Add(i.ToString()));

Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ForEach(i =>
{
    var row = table.NewRow();
    Enumerable.Range(0, 100).ForEach(j => row[j.ToString()] = Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    table.Rows.Add(row);
});

dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
```

Now I launch my program, move the window so that a part of it is covered by my taskbar and use a scrollbar. Suddenly all the data is messed up:

**UPDATE:**

```
partial class Form1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing && (components != null))
        {
            components.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    #region Windows Form Designer generated code

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(986, 758);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(986, 758);
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        this.ResumeLayout(false);

    }

    #endregion

    private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
}
```

[image]

What is the reason behind this?

Comment: When does the above code run?

Comment: @Alex it adds data to a DataGridView which was docked on the form via designer. It happens during the form's constuctor.

Comment: The question is "When" not "Why". Inside which method, when this method gets called. I would put a break point to see if it doesn't run multiple times.

Comment: @Alex I see what you are saying but it has nothing to do with the code being run twice. It is a problem related to repainting or other graphic-related methods. I also double checked for it being run twice just in case and no - it doesn't run twice.

Comment: Not seeing the relevant code I can only  guess that you may need to add a dgv.Refresh() to the Scroll event of the dgv. If it flickers or delays add DoubleBuffering!

Comment: Does the DataGridView have an `Invalidate` method? try calling it when the DataGridView scrolls

Comment: @TaW - not sure why code added by designer would be needed, but I added it. I do absolutely nothing except drag and dropping a DataGridView from the toolbox and setting it as dock-Fill - all via designer in Visual Studio. I also do not understand why I should add any additional code to Microsoft's controls, but I guess I can try.

Comment: _code added by designer would be needed_ Well, no it isn't. I just thought there would be more.. And it also always important to have a clear view of just from where a pice of code is called! -  _add any additional code to Microsoft's controls_ Well that is not a rare thing at all..

Comment: @Alex not perfectly, but this does solve the problem. Please do post it as an answer if you can :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as a solution the `.Invalidate()` method can be used. Although it is not the best way. More about invalidate method can be found here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

in my case the issue was that
some DataGridView cells background color were set to transparent

```
g[x,y].Style.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```